# Objective-C how do I use both codes and the Storyboard to design the UI?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a beginner of developing ios. I use the following codes from website to design part of the UI of my app.

```
   @implementation ViewController
NSMutableArray *allImgViews;
NSMutableArray *allCenters;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
allImgViews=[NSMutableArray new];
allCenters=[NSMutableArray new];

int xCen=46;  //xCen=RectLength/2; RectLength= viewLength/4=192
int yCen=46;

for(int v=0;v<4;v++)
{
    for (int h=0;h<4;h++)
    {  UIImageView* myImgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(30,23,93,93)];

        CGPoint curCen=CGPointMake(xCen, yCen);
        [allCenters addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:curCen]];

        myImgView.center=curCen;
        myImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"jc_%02i.jpg", h+v*4]];// picture names: jc_00.jpg -- jc_15.jpg
        myImgView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        [allImgViews addObject:myImgView];
        [self.view addSubview:myImgView];
        xCen+=93;//RectLength

    }
    xCen=46;
    yCen+=93;

}
[[allImgViews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
[allImgViews removeObjectAtIndex:0];

[self randomizeBlocks];

}
```

Now I want use the storyboard to design rest part of UI. I was wondering if it's possible to do that. If possible, how should I do that? Please help me. I have searched the website, but no answers. Many of the answers are old because Apple updates programing for Xcode 7 and iOS 9 development very quickly.

Comment: Your code started from your current UI design in the XIB. You should do everything you wanted to do using IB, then the rest with the `ViewController` class.

Comment: If you have not done much coding, i would suggest you to go for Storyboard's or Xibs.

Comment: @Zhi-WeiCai So you mean I can't use both codes in xib and the storyboard(IB) to design the Interface? There is one sentence is Apple's guide for IB: " Open the Assistant when editing your Storyboard or .xib file to quickly connect UI controls to the code that implements their behavior. "

Comment: @Zhi-WeiCai [continue..] It mainly says the code is to implement some behavior of some UI elements. So either I use storyboard to design the whole UI, or I only use codes to design the UI and its relevant events(behavior). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Since IB is more like a WYSIWYG editor, you can simply layout those you can, then do the adjustments with the code. IB is just an easier way to make and see the layout. At least from the code you showed, I didn't see any reason it has anything to do with IB side, before or after.